# Align table header (mat-header-cell) right

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

For some columns of my table (I'm using [angular material tables](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) v10), I want to have a right alignment. It's quite easy to do it for the cells themselfs with the `align` attribute: `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let u" align="right">{{u.rating}}</td>`

However doint the same with the `<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header align="right">Rating</th>` is just not working.

Searching for a solution I came across a lot of css adjustments like this:

```css
.mat-header-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
 }
```

But these were just messing up the formatting.

I'm a bit suprised, that material doesn't provide a simple way of doing this. I created a sample application that already right-align the cells:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnqztk

Any suggestions on how to align the headers as well?

**Solution**

Nikhil Walvekar found the correct solution (see the comments of the post). He fixed it in the linked stackblitz project. Simply add

```css
.text-right .mat-sort-header-container {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

to the global css file and add `text-right` to the header tag

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-right">Market Cap</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use mat-text-column which supports alignment.

```
<mat-text-column [name]="column" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay" justify="right">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" align="right"> {{element[column]}} </td>
</mat-text-column>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnqztk-kwajho?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html

Here is documentation link
https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTextColumn

Comment: Well, this solves the alignment problem. But now I cannot sort the column anymore.

Comment: My bad did not check the sorting before.
sort-header is adding additional elements that are creating the issue with alignment.
I have fixed the same stackblitz with a global style.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using **mat-sort** with the table, there are the arrows on the right of the headers which are visible on hover. So they occupy the space.

If you want to have the right alignment of the headers. You just remove the sorting from the table and then add the following lines in your css. Only by adding two lines the headers would be right-aligned.

```
table th{
  text-align:right
}
```

Comment: The space occupied by the arrow is minimal. Omitting the soring functionality is not an option.